# MongoDB and Spring Data - Is polymorphism a good idea?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, database-design, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Let's say I have three types of documents and what's differs them are some fields. Suppose:

1. For type A: we have `field1` **and** `field2`
2. For type B: we have only `field1` **but no** `field2`
3. For type C: we have `field3`

All other fields are the same. Would that be a good idea to represent the data using three classes inheriting from a base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a reminder :

Inheritance has two sides : [code reusing and overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Applications).
The first one solves the duplication issue (looks like your idea)  while the second defines for a same concept distinct behavior implementations.
Of course in some cases you may benefit from both sides.

About your question :

> Would that be a good idea to represent the data using three classes
>   inheriting from a base class?

If A, B and C are designed **only** to hold data ( so no logic/behavior inside) factoring the common fields (that is all fields but field1, field2 and field3) in a base class makes sense.  It will spare you duplication and duplication is a bad smell.
In the other hand, if A, B and C have also logic, you should introduce a base class only if these classes represent the same general concept.  Otherwise your abstraction is wrong and may lead to a messy usage where we try to manipulate uniformally (via the base class) things that actually are different concepts.